# RewriteRule for multiple URL matches in one line

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I currently use the following lines in my .htaccess file to rewrite several subdirectory URLs to the root of my website:

```
RewriteRule ^work(.*)$ $1
RewriteRule ^why-me(.*)$ $1
RewriteRule ^prices(.*)$ $1
RewriteRule ^contact(.*)$ $1
```

However, is there a way of expressing this in just one line instead?

I tried:

```
RewriteRule ^(work|why-me|prices|contact)(.*)$ $1
```

But (unsurprisingly, given my complete lack of knowledge when it comes to regexes), it didn't work and resulted in all these URLs giving me 404 errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteRule "^(work|why-me|prices|contact)(.*)$" "$2"
```

or

```
RewriteRule "^(?:work|why-me|prices|contact)(.*)$" "$1"
```

$1 refers to the first capturing group, which is whatever you defined in the first set of parenthesis.  Since you've created another set within parenthesis, $1 no longer refers to what follows, but instead contains `work`,`why-me`, etc.

The first solution needs to be $2 because $1 will be one of: work,why-me, etc. and $2 will be whatever follows it.

The second solution works by using a non-capturing group for the first group (It isn't numbered), so `(.*)` will put it's part into $1 instead of $2.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a non-capturing group since `$1` now represents all directory names:

```
RewriteRule ^(?:work|why-me|prices|contact)(.*)$ $1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: how can we avoid the patter /..;/ in the url https://domainname/..;/manager/html,  Using the regex ^/^((?!.;).)* in RewriteURL, it only consideres the first occurance of pattern in URI query string(/..;/manager/html).                                    RewriteRule ^/(.*) /app/$1 [PT] , please suggest.

Comment: @Prabha: Please post a question with details and I will attend.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot, please check the url : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63742004/two-consecutive-dots-in-url-moves-the-url-navigation-one-step-backward, for complete details.