# Two consecutive dots in URL moves the URL navigation one step backward

Tags: tomcat, url, servlets

I have few doubts regarding the usage of the pattern dot-dot-semicolon in the URL(to access servlet app deployed in apache tomcat webapps folder). Using dot-dot-semicolon(`/..;/`) makes the url back to one step.
The original issue(only dot-dot pattern) is a directory traversal vulnerability which has been resolved in latest version than tomcat `6.0.18` , `domainname/../manager/html` normalized to `domainname/manager/html`(404 error). But in `6.0.37`,we can re-produce the same vulnerability with dot-dot-semicolon as `domainname/..;/manager/html`, then we can access the tomcat internal folder such as admin url and it prompts me the credentials of tomcat manager username and password. Here `domainname` is the client URL accessed the servlet app deployed in tomcat and the client url is configured in `httpd.conf` as

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
DocumentRoot /usr/local/apache/htdocs/EMPTY

JkMount /* ajp13
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/(.*) /he/$1 [PT]
</VirtualHost *:80>
```

Can we use any expression for `RewriteRule` to avoid the pattern(`https://domainname/..;`)  for the below request URL's

```
"https://domainname/..;======/xxx/yyyy"
"https://domainname/..;/xxx/yyyy"
"https://domainname/..;abcd/xxx/yyyy"


virtual host settings in apache httpd.conf
<VirtualHost :80>
DocumentRoot /usr/local/apache/htdocs/EMPTY ServerName client.website.com 
RewriteEngine On # Redirect all requests to the local Apache server to port 
8000 
RewriteRule ^/?(.) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L] 
</VirtualHost>
```

Please suggest.

Thank you

Comment: Hi, how to avoid '../' pattern exists after the domain name in the URL https://domainname.com/..;/manager/html with the help of .htaccess file. Please suggest the correct rule for this unique requirement.

Comment: Can you check your Apache access log for a request in browser that has URL as:  `https://domainname/..;/manager/html`

Comment: Thank you, checking for the same logs in production, I could fix this direct traversal issue in tomcat server with the RewritrRule change from 'RewriteRule ^/(.*) /webapplication/$1 [PT]' to 'RewriteRule ^/^((?!..;).)* /webapplication/$1 [PT]' .                                              
       As the issue is with the pattern ..; after the domain name, so I am using (?!..;)  with not equal to symbol to avoid this. Please check the RegEx  ^/^((?!..;).)* to avoid /..;/aaa/bbb/ccc .

Comment: Hi, I came across a similar issue and realized that this regex will ignore some cases for example ..;/..; or ..;;/ the best way I could figure out was to not include in rewrite url xml file but in a separate filter and then look for (\.+;+) and on matching simply throw a 404 exception.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change this behaviour.

Most browsers will normalize (convert /aaa/bbb/../ccc into /aaa/ccc) before the request is even sent to the server. If such a request reaches Tomcat, Tomcat will always normalise it before processing. This is for security to prevent, for example, bypassing of security constraints. There is no way to disable this and any requests for a feature to allow disabling this will almost certainly be rejected.

For the the URLs you quote where `/../` follows immediately after the host, Tomcat will return a 400 response. Again, browsers may well change such URLs if you try entering them in the address bar.

Comment: @Markm Thank you, I updated the question with clear details, can you please check it once.

Comment: Which versions, exactly, are you using for mod_jk and Tomcat?

Comment: it's a version apache-tomcat-6.0.37, and there is a servlet app in webapps and the client URL's are configured in Virtualhost host redirect setup as :  
<VirtualHost *:80>
 DocumentRoot /usr/local/apache/htdocs/EMPTY
 ServerName client.website.com
 RewriteEngine On
 # Redirect all requests to the local Apache server to port 8000
 RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
</VirtualHost>,    To resolve the issue I changed RewriteRule as "RewriteRule ^/((?!..;).*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L] ", Now it's working and url http://domainname/..;/manager/html redirects to 404.

Comment: Tomcat 6 reached end-of-life on 31 December 2016. You need to upgrade to a supported version of Tomcat. I'd recommend at least 8.5.x and preferably 9.0.x.
You also haven't provided the mod_jk version details requested.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the update, will provide mod_k details asap, we already suggested to upgrade tomcat version but due to no support from the corresponding team they decided to not upgrade the tomcat version. Can you please take a look of the following  details: Please check the virtual host setup details in the question(at bottom), I rewrite the RewriteRule  rule regex from ^/?(.) to  ^/((?!..;).*)  , Now it's working with out issues , when user tries http://domainname/..;/manager/html , as per the configuration it does not redirects the request to https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1, then it shows 404.